# KeyError: 'allow_remote_access' in jupyter notebook in one environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I can run jupyter notebook without activating environment. Also I can run in under environment `py35` I made. But when I try to run it under `py36`, it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

This can't be solved with editing file in ~/.jupyter, because it works in other envs.

Answer (score 7):

Just pass manually option --ip with correct IP instead of *:

```
jupyter notebook --ip="0.0.0.0"
```

or change in your config file

Details: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/718

Comment: A helpful link here as well
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3946#issuecomment-423169943

Answer (score 2):

I remember I fixed this point by adding the following change in the config file of jupyter.

Here are the steps :

1. `vi ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`
2. Insert this : `c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'`
3. exit the config file and run `jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8899` (8899 is the port number, you have to change it ;) )

You can do this whether you worked on the cloud or on your local machine.